# How to combine two, separate 4 bit words into a 6 bit one?

Tags: digital-logic, programmable-logic

How to combine two, 4-bit words into one 6-bit word.

What I want to achieve: Using a matrix keyboard, I would like to control six addresses (A0-A5) of a parallel EEPROM memory in the range from 000000 to 111111. After selecting two decimal numbers on the matrix keyboard, for example, '2' and '3', I would get two 4-bit words (0010) and (0011) at the output, from which I would then like to obtain the number '23' as a 6-bit word (010111). What logic operations should I perform to achieve this result?

This is a part of my project - a binary music / pulse sequencer based on logic gates. The sequencer works in two modes - the first is generating 64 sequences of 8 pulses (triggers) each. Each single sequence is recorded using an ADC, via a potentiometer. In other words, one 'step' is one 8-bit sequence. After recording 64 combinations, the sequencer is switched to playback mode in a loop - from 0-63. It is possible to reset at any time using an external clock and reset signal. The second mode is playback of 8 waveforms stored in the EEPROM memory, 64 bytes each, which allow for modulation (e.g., LFO) through the DAC. Both modes of the sequencer can be used simultaneously - you can control an external device using the generated pulses and also modulate - both modes, however, are synchronized using the same clock. Increasing the speed of the pulses at the sequencer output increases the frequency of the modulation waveforms. The sequencer also has an LFSR source and a 'glide' function. The 'glide' function is a circuit at the DAC output that 'softens' voltage jumps.
[image]

The memory cell number is displayed here:
[image]

The part of the circuit controls the memory cells with the clock:
[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen if the selection is, for example, "85"?

Comment: You can use any logic operations you want. It does not matter how the result ends up being what it is. But you might want to be clear that when you push '2' and '3' it means 23 in decimal? If so, do you recall how decimal numbers work?

Comment: perform BCD to binary conversion

Comment: @ThePhoton That's a good point - everything above 64 should be ignored.

Comment: @Justme Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I don't want to add '2' and '3' together, but to get '23' - exactly as you enter a number on a calculator before performing any arithmetic operation.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki You push '2', multiply it by 10, you get 20, push '3' and add it, and get 23. The other thing is, it might be harder to work in decimals than in binary, hex, or octal. Where is this matrix keyboard connected, what output you get and where? To digital logic? To an MCU running code?

Comment: It seems way easier to enter the address as two digits base 8. Do you intend to `[select two] numbers on [one and the same] matrix keyboard`?

Comment: @jsotola Converting from BCD to binary for a single number from the keyboard will work, but how to perform the conversion in the case of two numbers that do not have any simple, arithmetic relationship? '2' and '3' do not make '23' through addition, multiplication, etc. To do what you suggest, I would first have to multiply '2' by '10', and then add '3'. So, should the logic operation on the gates result from the system of multiplying the first number and adding the second...?

Comment: @Justme The matrix keyboard is to be connected to a 74922 decoder. yes, digital logic.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki I have to wonder what is the motivation for this project? Is this school work?

Comment: @greybeard If I understand your question correctly, it is always one keyboard on which I sequentially choose two numbers. Indeed, maybe it would suffice to stay in the binary system, and control the address pins with only 6 bits?

Comment: @Justme no, It's just my project - a binary sequencer based entirely on logic gates. No microprocessor. So this functionality comes to my mind - to access memory cells directly with the keyboard.

Comment: ***If*** your keyboard outputs encoded digits along with a *strobe*, two registers of at least 3 bits each to capture the last two keys would be useful. Alternatively, a serial in, parallel out shift register of at least 6 bits if you go binary entry. Check whether you're OK with "addresses in transit": parts of the previous address combined with parts of the new one.

Comment: *"It's just my project - a binary sequencer based entirely on logic gates. No microprocessor."* For the work that people would put into a decent answer (not just one listing the sequence steps), can you first explain in good detail why this should be done? *"It's just my project"* is pretty insufficient to me, much as I encourage designs for exploration and understanding.

Comment: @JerzyP Provide some details on your keyboard entry. What exactly is it and how will a strobe be generated to capture the key value? (May need a schmitt trigger to create a clean strobe.)

Comment: @TonyM I have added a short description. Hope this looks better.

Comment: @greybeard I have added a 3rd schematic that shows control / clock section. 4024 strobes the address and decimal counter in the same time. So the display shows an actual state / memory cell with a number.

Comment: As in *There are two counters with common reset, clock & modulus, so due to being in lockstep, the number displayed should be the address applied to the EEPROM's A₀…A₅*? Thinking out of the box, obscure and not helpful when the address comes from manual entry.

Comment: @greybeard The only reason for entering the address from the keyboard is the need for a quick jump to any location in the range of 0-63. Note that now it is only possible to manually move the counter forward by one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the 1st number. Have an adder which uses it as the first number to be added together as shifted left by 1 bit position and then shifted left by 3 bit positions. That's multiply by 10. Then add the 2nd number. Turn on the error flag if the result is not 0....63.

This sequence can be performed without programmable devices. I guess that was the way to make things as late as 45...50 years ago.

*If you can program a processor, multiply the 1st number by 10 and add the second number. That's already said more than once as "do BCD to binary conversion" Check the range.*

*As well you could fill the memory so that you get the right numbers out when you use 8 address bits and use the first number as Addr0...Addr3 and the second number as Addr4...Addr7. You must have a free output code for "invalid input". Its existence is not clear, because you didn't tell do more address bits come from elsewhere.*

ADD: The italicized text part of the answer became obsolete when the question was edited to close out these possibilities by inserting a schematic. I must admit it's not at all clear what useful or interesting the circuit does (other than raises some thinking "what it might be?"), but that can be only my limitation.

Comment: Thanks will try that.